# WebApi CORS and No Transport

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cors

I need help as I am experiencing something that I cannot find an answer to solve the problem.

I have a asp.net mvc webapi running on site A and another site running on site B. This i believe fits the definition of cross site. Therefore I have nuget 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors' and added the "config.EnableCors();" to the Register metohd of the WebApiConfig.cs. I have also added to the web.config of the Site A

```
   <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
            <!-- Latest Browser Mode-->
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Further to this i have added [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] to the controller base class that i am using.

I think this is everything i need to enable cors for the webapi site.

On site B i have a javascript function that uses the following:

```
 $.ajax({                
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                if (window.console) console.log("Error with ajax call: " + err);
                $('#findCustomer').text('Error: ' + err);
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                var headerValue = "Basic <somecode>";
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', headerValue);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that I keep hitting the error handler of the ajax call and the err is "no transport". Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: look at the headers of your ajax, maybe you are not allowing the proper headers. try <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" /> (don't know if that's allowed). At least add the authorization one you are explicit setting in the beforeSend function.

Comment: Having a bit of difficulty doing that as even fiddler is not showing a request leaving as a result of this piece of code.

NOTE: fiddler is showing the page load but no request after this code is run. I have put hte debugger on the page and can verify that the code gets to this piece of code.

Comment: so browser is stoping the request... change dataType to 'jsonp' ?

Comment: It gets out, but the url has parameters and when the &callback=<function> is added the error SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' is thrown. Also the result being sent back from the request is a JSon string

Comment: checkout my answer with code updated and see if that gets thru!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry All, the problem came down to the windows server 2003 not recognising the IE 1 browser and defaulting to a IE mode that did not support the jquery call.

How i reolved this issue:

1. Web Developer tools and looked at the "Emulation" tab.
2. Notices the "Document mode" was ie 8(default).
3. Changed this to "Edge" or "10" and everything worked.
4. Created an "app_browser" folder in the solution.
5. Created an "ie.browser" file.
6. Copied the latest windows server 2012 "ie.broswer" file content into this created file.
7. published the site.
8. All good :)

NOTE: the windows server 2012 "ie.browser" file must be the latest with the hot fixes appplied.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Change dataType to 'jsonp'.

Also, crossDomain property is not required:

according to jQuery documentation:

> ```
> crossDomain (default: false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests)
> Type: Boolean
> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for
> ```
>
> example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added:
>   1.5)

Also, as jQuery Documentation, `X-Requested-With` header is always added so you must accept that header too.

Also on jQuery Documentation :

> jsonp Type: String Override the callback function name in a jsonp
>   request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the
>   'callback=?' part of the query string in the url. So
>   {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in 'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the
>   server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents
>   jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to
>   use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly
>   set the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false,
>   jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

so, set jsonp to false

updated code should be :

```
$.ajax({                
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "callbackName",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            if (window.console) console.log("Error with ajax call: " + err);
            $('#findCustomer').text('Error: ' + err);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            var headerValue = "Basic <somecode>";
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', headerValue);
        }
    });
function callbackName() { console.log('worked');}
```

Comment: 1. Change the Web.Config to be <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
2. Change the jquery call to refect the above, but am getting the SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' when I think it is try to parse the json object returned like it is javascript.

Comment: i added jsonCallback in last update because doc requires this explicitly.

Comment: Added Callback as follows:
jsonpCallback: function (data) {
                    alert("success = " + data);
                },
however the data is undefined and the Script error still occurs.

Comment: callback is a string not a function. the function with the name must exist but the parameter on the ajax must be a string. added callbackName() function.

Comment: Sorry, but the string is simply a delegate to the function and a function declaration is acceptable as well.

Comment: You are right on the function delcaration is acceptable, sorry. Further reading leads me to think that you must use JSON not JSONP and the access-control must be enabled propertly. Revert back to json and see if the Access-Control-Allow-Headers was enough. if not, i can't help you much further this point :( For JSONP to work you must change the server response which is not what you want actually.